# Inputting Data with Haskell

Tags: shell, haskell, functional-programming, io, machine-learning

**Back Story**: In an attempt to better understand Haskell and functional programming, I've given myself a few assignments. My first assignment is to make a program that can look through a data set (a set of numbers, words in a blog, etc), search for patterns or repetitions, group them, and report them.

Sounds easy enough. :)

**Question**: I'd like for the program to start by creating a list variable from the data in a text file. I'm familiar with the *readFile* function, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to input data.

For example, I'd like to allow the user to type something like this in the command line to load the program and the data set.

> ./haskellprogram textfile.txt

Is there a function that will allow this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  -- args is a list of arguments
  if null args
    then putStrLn "usage: ./haskellprogram textfile.txt"
    else do contents <- readFile $ head args
            putStrLn $ doSomething contents

doSomething :: String -> String
doSomething = reverse
```

That should be enough to get you started. Now replace `reverse` with something more valuable :)

Speaking of parsing some input data, you might consider breaking your data into [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:lines) or [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:words) using respective functions from Prelude.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't able to compile this code though. Or is it just pseudocode, as an example?

Comment: @SubtleArray, I'm glad I could help. Could you elaborate on _wasn't able to compile_? It's not pseudocode. It might compile after the recent change. Give it a try.

Comment: ghc got a little grumpy at this part _source.hs:10:13: Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[Char]'_, but all is well now. I appreciate your time and help. Now that the hard part has been worked out, I can get started on the easy stuff. (:D Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [getArgs](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsystem/getArgs_f.html) function.

Comment: This really is the best site ever. :D

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Subtle Array, I can never resist mentioning my favorite when I was first learning Haskell, `interact`:

```
 module Main where
 main = interact doSomething

 doSomething :: String -> String
 doSomething xs = reverse xs
```

you then use it as `cat textfile.txt | ./haskellprogram | grep otto` or whatever.  There is also a variant in `Data.Text` which you might get to know, and a few others in other string-ish libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Playing with the relatively new [ReadArgs package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ReadArgs):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import ReadArgs (readArgs)

main = do
  (fname :: String, foo :: Int) <- readArgs
  putStrLn fname
```

Testing...

```
$ runhaskell args.hs blahblah 3
blahblah
```

One irritation with `readArgs` is that it doesn't work if you have only a single argument. [Hmmm...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752532/make-readargs-work-with-a-single-argument)

Once you have the desired file name as a `String`, you can use `readFile` as usual.