# Call main function with arguments

Tags: haskell

I have problem with reading from file. Whenever I need to read from a file, I do something like this:

```
main = do x <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt"
      putStr x
```

But now I would like the path to be an argument, so I tried the following

```
main s = do x <- readFile s
        putStr x
```

It doesn't work. I see the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0'
            with actual type `FilePath -> IO ()'
In the expression: main
When checking the type of the function `main'
```

My homework is to write a program and the program has to contain a main function (because it will be compiled) and argument of call must contain the name of the file. I'm not sure I understand this and I don't know how to proceed. I will grateful for some help.

Comment: Very basic, but also very valid question. I am surprised that it has not been asked before, but did not find an exact duplicate with a quick search. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747780/inputting-data-with-haskell/) is quite similar, though.

Answer (score 18):

The [Haskell report specifies](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html) that the `main` function always has type `IO t`, (for some type `t` which will be ignored) and hence never takes normal function arguments, so this is not the right approach.

You are looking for the function [`getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs) (for which you have to import the module `System.Environment`. It returns the arguments passed to your program as a list of `String`s.

So your code would look like:

```
import System.Environment
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of 
      [file] -> do
        x <- readFile file
        putStr x
      _ -> putStrLn "Wrong number of arguments"
```

Comment: Ok, and now I can call main function as     :main "/tmp/foo.txt" ?

Comment: No, you can compile your program (`ghc main.hs`) and then run it as `./main /tmp/foo.txt`.

Comment: Yes you can, but leave out the parenthesis, i.e. write `:main /tmp/foo.txt` (just as you would pass command line parameters).

Comment: If now you didn't call `main` a _function_... the Haskell report gets it right: "...must be called `Main` and must export the **value** `main`". If it was a function then it surely would indeed accept the command-line parameters as its argument; but `IO t` is just an action.

Answer (score 8):

In Haskell, the arguments are NOT given to the main function because of the way Haskell binds its start up and to remain consistent.  You need to use [`System.Environment.getArgs`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Environment.html#v%3AgetArgs).

In particular, because Haskell is a pure functional language, `main` is a monadic action that organizes the side-effect-ful computations performed by the software – the result computed by `main` is discarded, because in functional languages you are detached from the environment w.r.t. computation and only interact with it as a side-effect.

## Example

```
import System.Environment

main = do x <- getArgs; print x
```

This will print out whatever you type on the command line.

[The Haskell wiki has an excellent tutorial on the topic.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials/Programming_Haskell/Argument_handling)